# Java Interlocked Threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm getting interlocked threads in somewhat simple producer/consumer (and based on examples correct) code.

There is a thread executing this:

```
    public void append(final Object obj) {
        buffer.add(obj);

        if (buffer.size() >= BUFFER_MAX_SIZE) {
            insertLock.lock();
            switchLock.lock();
            insertLock.unlock();

            bufferFull.signal();
            try {
                bufferSwitch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            switchLock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

There is another thread with this code:

```
        try {
            insertLock.lock();
            while (true) {
                switchLock.lock();
                insertLock.unlock();
                bufferFull.await();
                switchBuffers();
                bufferSwitch.signal();
                insertLock.lock();
                switchLock.unlock();

                if (insertBuffer.size() > 0) {
                    db.insert(insertBuffer);
                    insertBuffer.clear();
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

As I mentioned it is based on the producer/consumer example on the Condition API documentation. I can't detect why both threads get stuck on the conditions await method.

Is there any error ? Looks like there is something my naked eyes can't see.

Thank you,

PS: Added working code.

Answer (score 1):

Thread A does

```
        insertLock.lock();
        switchLock.lock();
```

and Thread B does

```
        switchLock.lock();
        ....
        insertLock.lock();
```

So if Thread A acquires `insertLock` while B gets `switchLock`, neither A nor B can proceed to the next line.

Comment: The idea is to switch the buffers as fast as possible. In the case of the production being too fast I should assure that the data is fully inserted before switching buffers again.

I try to lock the insert lock to assure that it's not inserting data. If I lock it, it's not inserting data, so I can continue locking the switch lock to wait for the full buffer signal.

The mistery for me in this case is that I get in the situation where full buffer is signaled from the append data before run method gets to the full buffer await. Is not locked trying to get locks.

PS: I fixed the locks order.

Answer (score 0):

It's a clasic [deadlock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html) situation. You should always make sure the locks are getting locked in the same order.

For a producer/consumer problem with threads you could look at the [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) interface and its derived classes that java offers.

For example:

```
package cl.mds.migracion;

import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;

public class Example {

    static ArrayBlockingQueue<String> buffer = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(5);

    static class Producer  implements Runnable{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500); //seleep 500ms to simulate producer time
                    buffer.put(String.valueOf(i)); //put waits the thread until there is size in the queue.
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    static class Consumer implements Runnable{

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100); //seleep 100ms to simulate slower consumer tha producer
                    System.out.printf("Consuming %s ....%n",buffer.take()); //take waits the thread until there is something in the queue
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.printf("Starting producer/consumer ....%n");
        new Thread(new Producer()).start();
        new Thread(new Consumer()).start();
        System.out.printf("Finishing ....%n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I considered a BlockingQueue but I wanted to work with as much as possible objects, that's why I opted for using locks and conditions.